# CMake Error at CMakeLists.txt:50 (find_package): Could not find a package configuration file provided by "fbjni" with any of the following names:

Tags: android, react-native, kotlin, gradle

I have tried to run react native android version app, and it will give following error.

Error:

> CMake Error at CMakeLists.txt:85 (find_package):
> Could not find a package configuration file provided by "ReactAndroid" with
> any of the following names:
> CMake Error at CMakeLists.txt:50 (find_package):
> Could not find a package configuration file provided by "fbjni" with any of
> the following names:

Log:
[image: Error log]

Project level build.gradle
[image: Project build.gradle]

Kotlin version

[image: App Level build gradle kotlin version]

Comment: is it solved already ?